# Kubernetes: single POD with many container, or many Pod with single container

Tags: kubernetes, microservices

I've rather a teoretical question which I can't answer  with the reousrces found online. The question is: **what's the rule to decide how to compose containers in POD?** . Let me explain with an example.

I've these microservices:

- Authentication
- Authorization
- Serving content
- (plus) OpenResty to forward the calls form one to the other and orhcestarate the flow. (is there a possibility to do so natively in K8?, it seems to have services base on nginx+lua, but not sure how it works)

*For the sake of the example I avoid Databases and co, I assume they are external and not managed by kubernetes*

Now, what's the correct way here *LEFT* or *RIGHT* of the image?
[image]

*LEFT* : this seems easier to make it working, everything works on "localhost" , the downside is that it looses a bit the benefit of the microservices. For example, if the auth become slows and it would need more instances, I've to duplicate the whole pod and not just that service.

*RIGHT* seems a bit more complex, need services to expose each POD to the other PODs. Yet, here, I could duplicate auth as I need without duplicating the other containers. On the other hand I'll have a lot of pods since each pod is basically a container.

Answer (score 2):

It is generally recommended to keep different services in different pods or better deployments that will scale independently. The reasons are what is generally discussed as benefits of a microservices architecture.

- A more loose coupling allowing the different services to be developed independently in their own languages/technologies,
- be deployed and updated independently and
- also to scale independently.

The exception are what is considered a "*helper application*" to assist a "primary application". Examples given in the k8s docs are data pullers, data pushers and proxies. In those cases a share file system or exchange via loopback network interface can help with critical performance use cases. A data puller can be a side-car container for an nginx container pulling a website to serve from a GIT repository for example.

Answer (score 1):

right image, each in own pod.  multi containers in a pod should really only be used when they are highly coupled or needed for support of the main container such as a data loader.

With separate pods, it allows for each service to be updated and deployed independently.  It also allows for more efficient scaling. in the future, you may need 2 or 3 content pods but still only one authorization. if they are all together you scale them all since you don't have a choice with them all together in the same pod.

Answer (score 0):

Right image is better option. Easier management, upgrades, scaling.

Answer (score 0):

Should choose the right side of the structure, on the grounds that the deployment of the left side of the architecture model is tight coupling is not conducive to a module according to the actual needs of the business expansion capacity.